# Properly read a url from local.properties on WIndows

Tags: windows, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to read a `URL` stored in the `local.properties` file of an Android project.

```
MAPBOX_STYLE_URL=mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10
```

The `URL` is read in `Gradle` (`Groovy`) like so:

```
Properties localProperties = new Properties()
String propertyValue = new File(localProperties[propertyName])
buildConfigField("String", "MAPBOX_STYLE_URL", "\"" + propertyValue + "\"")
```

This makes the `URL` available for the `Android` `Java` `classes` to use. By using the generated `BuildConfig` `class`. The generated parameter on `BuildConfig` looks like this on `Windows`:

```
public static final String MAPBOX_STYLE_URL = "mapbox:\styles\mapbox\light-v10";
```

As you can see, the `URL` is incorrect as the forward dashes have become backslashes.

This system works on `MacOS` to load the `URL` with no problem, but it is not working on `Windows`.

Is there a special way to escape the characters on the `local.properties` file on `Windows` so that they are loaded properly?

Perhaps a different way to load the properties on Gradle so that they are loaded correctly independent of the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to load the properties differently and the parsing now works the same way on Windows and MacOS

```
String propertyValue = localProperties[propertyName]
```